# Publicar Core Web Application com Authentication no Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-azure

Criei uma aplicação Core Web Application , com o Visual Studio 2019 e a publiquei seguindo exatamente o passo a passo indicado em https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.1

A aplicação é basicamente uma tela de registro e login.

- Criei o projeto escolhendo individual User Accounts
- Registrei um user com o app rodando local e cliquei em Apply Migrations
- Criei o Azure App Service pelo wizard do VS
- Criei o Azure SQL Database pelo wizard do VS
- Ajustei as configs como no tutorial

Localmente funciona. **Na hora de publicar da erro** e fica tentando até 10 vezes
"Retrying operation 'Add' on object dbFullSql Attempt 5 of 10." até não conseguir e dar erro sem explicar mais.

Percebi que nos Settings de Publish se eu desmarcar a opção *Apply this migration on publish* consegue publicar. Mas na hora de usar o app publicado, como registrar um usuário, da erro.

Conferi no painel do azure, está tudo criado lá, inclusive o banco. Como posso fazer para essa opção Apply this migration funcionar?

O valor está ok, tudo como no tutorial, com meu password da conexão:

Data Source=tcp:xxxxdbserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=WebApplication1_db;User Id=xxxx@xxxsdbserver;Password=XXXXXXX

Estou usando netcoreapp3.1

Answer (score 0):

Na instrução do link postado da microsoft diz
"Na próxima etapa da caixa de diálogo configurar banco de dados SQL do Azure :"
A prática recomendada é evitar o uso dos mesmos detalhes que o nome de usuário do administrador & senha usada na etapa anterior".

Porém, no meu caso, só funcionou usando o mesmo username e senha do administrador.